# Linux Booting Angel booting

Tags: linux, arm

I'm reading about linux/arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.S

I figured out about the `angel boot`. It's my first time about this word

```
#ifndef CONFIG_CPU_V7M
        /*
         * Booting from Angel - need to enter SVC mode and disable
         * FIQs/IRQs (numeric definitions from angel arm.h source).
         * We only do this if we were in user mode on entry.
         */
        mrs r2, cpsr        @ get current mode
        tst r2, #3          @ not user?
        bne not_angel
        mov r0, #0x17       @ angel_SWIreason_EnterSVC
 ARM(       swi 0x123456    )   @ angel_SWI_ARM
 THUMB(     svc 0xab        )   @ angel_SWI_THUMB
not_angel:
        safe_svcmode_maskall r0
        msr spsr_cxsf, r9       @ Save the CPU boot mode in
                        @ SPSR
#endif
```

So i googled and read the linux documentation located in `linux/Documentation/arm/Booting`

There's no clear definition about angel booting in any website and linux documentation only mentioned angel as like bellow

```
  For CPUs which do not include the ARM virtualization extensions, the
  CPU must be in SVC mode.  (A special exception exists for Angel)
```

So I want to know about clear definition about angel boot

Thank you for your answer

Comment: The slightly tricky connection to make is that Angel is the old name for ARM's standard [semihosting interface for external debuggers](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0471m/pge1358787046598.html).

Comment: Angel is extremely old tech that was available on the StrongARM CPUs (circa 2000).  I would ignore it; that is why no one documented it.

Comment: Thank you for good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refers to the content from ARM Information center, "Angel is a debug monitor that allows rapid development and debugging of applications running on ARM-based hardware."
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0066d/Babdcdih.html

It seems you can debug your software through Angel using debuggers like gdb - when your board is set up with Angel.

It offers a feature which is called "Semihosting" - a board-host input/output bridging. It is done on SWI context.
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0058d/CIHDICHH.html